# Elevated but not domain administrator Active Directory

Tags: powershell, administrator, active-directory

I've searched low and high, but I can't find anywhere that shows how to set an AD admin account that can run programs as admin but not be a domain admin in AD.

These accounts will be elevated account for shells in Powershell on the Domain Controller.

Sorry of this is a really 'User' question.

Thanks in advance.

W10

Server 2012

Comment: Your question does not make sense. An AD Administrator would trump any permission a local Administrator might have.  If you want user to be part of the local Administrator group then you need to add that user group.  If you want to use a local Administrator account then you would have not not prefix/indicate the domain when you log into the user thus using a local profile.  What you want to do does not make sense, why do you want to run as a local administrator, instead of an AD administrator?

Comment: I dont' want to be able to make changes to the domain but still be able to run PowerShell as admin, due to some of the Scripts we have to run, having a local account would bind us to a single machine which renders it useless for the purposes we need.

Comment: **So create a new user group with only the permission you require to run the script.**  You don't indicate which permissions the script requires, so the best I can do, is suggest a new user group.

Comment: It will be different scripts that will require different things but the main issue is how to create an admin account that doesn't have domain admin creds.

Comment: [How to Make a Domain User the Local Administrator for all PCs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7833.how-to-make-a-domain-user-the-local-administrator-for-all-pcs.aspx)